# XHTML Parsing with HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a list of the following  elements inside a  element that I have found using HTMLAgilityPack.

```
<option value="67"><span style="color: #cc0000;">Horde</span> Leveling / Dailies & Event Guide ($50.00)</option>
```

What I need to do is parse all the text out of the  tag, without all the  mumbo jumbo in there. I've tried (seemingly!) everything, but it always comes out looking like this:

> Horde
>   Leveling / Dailies & Event Guide ($50.00)

and sometimes like:

> Horde
>   Leveling
>   / Dailies & Event Guide ($50.00)

and a couple other variations like that. I've even gone so far as to print out each character in the string as a byte, and I haven't found any linebreaks or feeds, only what I expected, normal letters and spaces. Here's the full source of the html for reference, copied straight from the page.

```
<option value="13"><span style="color: #0000ff;">Alliance</span> Leveling Guide ($30.00)</option>


<option value="12"><span style="color: #cc0000;">Horde</span> Leveling Guide ($30.00)</option>

<option value="46"><span style="color: #cc0000;">Horde</span> Dailies & Events Guide ($25.00)</option>

<option value="67"><span style="color: #cc0000;">Horde</span> Leveling / Dailies & Event Guide ($50.00)</option>


<option value="11"><span style="color: #0000ff;">Alliance</span> &amp; <span style="color: #cc0000;">Horde</span> Leveling Guide ($50.00)</option>

<option value="97"><span style="color: #0000ff;">Alliance</span> Achievements & Professions Guide ($20.00)</option>

<option value="98"><span style="color: #cc0000;">Horde</span> Achievements & Professions Guide ($20.00)</option>


<option value="99"><span style="color: #0000ff;">Alliance</span> &amp; <span style="color: #cc0000;">Horde</span> Achievements & Professions Guide ($30.00)</option>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? Are you using the InnerText-property of the html-nodes btw?

Answer (score 5):

By default, the `<OPTION>` tag is treated by Html Agility Pack as a "Empty", which means it does not need a closing `</OPTION>`, that's why in this case, it's not easy to catch with XPATH. You can change this using the HtmlNode.ElementFlags collection.

Here is a code that should do what you want:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");
doc.LoadHtml(yourHtml);
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//option"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: This is how I'm getting my element, it is getting the element just fine as I am doing it by Id, and not XPATH. What I am having problems with is the InnerText property itself, and how the formatting is coming out.
HtmlNode option = doc.GetElementbyId("pur_li");