# HtmlAgilityPack HtmlNode how to get <select> and <option> tag

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack HtmlNode and i want to get

```
<select> and <option> and all other html tags.
```

Currently HtmlNode parse only html, table, div,... tags. How can i get option and select tag too.

My current code:

```
if (htmlContent != null)
{
    doc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

    if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*") == null)
    {
        List<TagValuePair> tempList = new List<TagValuePair>();
        tempList.Add(new TagValuePair("Error!", htmlContent, -1));
        return tempList;
    }

    foreach (HtmlNode tag in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*"))
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag.InnerHtml))
            {
                if (!tagAppearance.Keys.Contains(tag.Name))
                {
                    tagAppearance.Add(tag.Name, 1);
                }
                else
                    tagAppearance[tag.Name] = tagAppearance[tag.Name] + 1;

                tagsValues.Add(
                    new TagValuePair(tag.Name, tag.InnerHtml.Trim(),
                    tagAppearance[tag.Name])
                );
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

i try with

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//option");
```

and i get option tags but no others. How to get all + option and select

EDIT:

need to get all data from option from this html:

```
<select onchange="javascript:submitGlobalDiscountSvetisce(this.value);submitGlobalDiscount(this.value);" name="datumper">
                  <option value="18.6.2011|7">18.jun. 7 noči od 515,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="25.6.2011|7">25.jun. 7 noči od 515,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="2.7.2011|7">2.jul. 7 noči od 515,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="9.7.2011|7">9.jul. 7 noči od 515,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="16.7.2011|7">16.jul. 7 noči od 515,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="23.7.2011|7">23.jul. 7 noči od 515,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="30.7.2011|7">30.jul. 7 noči od 529,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="6.8.2011|7">6.avg. 7 noči od 529,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="13.8.2011|7">13.avg. 7 noči od 529,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="20.8.2011|7">20.avg. 7 noči od 529,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="3.9.2011|7">3.sep. 7 noči od 487,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="10.9.2011|7">10.sep. 7 noči od 487,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="17.9.2011|7">17.sep. 7 noči od 487,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="24.9.2011|7">24.sep. 7 noči od 487,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="1.10.2011|7">1.okt. 7 noči od 529,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="8.10.2011|7">8.okt. 7 noči od 529,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="15.10.2011|7">15.okt. 7 noči od 529,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="22.10.2011|7">22.okt. 7 noči od 567,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="29.10.2011|7">29.okt. 7 noči od 567,00&nbsp;EUR</option>

                </select>
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, OPTION tags are treated specifically (for historic reasons). See my answer on this thread here on SO: [Parsing HTML Reading Option Tag Content with HtmlAgillityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758644/parsing-html-with-html-agillity-pack)

Comment: thx for answer. So i must manually parse option and all other tags and join it by union. Am i right?

Comment: @senzacionale - no, you need to use the ElementFlags; remove the "option" tag from there. See another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755486/xhtml-parsing-with-htmlagilitypack

Comment: if i use your code: foreach (HtmlNode node in docs.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@id='onoffaci']//option"))
 i get Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: i try your solution with docs.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//option"); and now i get all option tags. But there is no other html tag. Must i use union to join together html tag and option tag or can i do all this in one node?

Comment: @senzacionale - not sure I really understand. XPATH should support unions yes (with |)

Comment: hmm i need to get a html tags + option tags but i do not know how to join it together. Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @senzacionale - sorry I still do not understand :-) What data do you need? the option's inner text? the option value? which "other tags"?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//select[@id='idElement']").OuterHtml** this line bring select and options.

Happy Codes