# XPath queries using HtmlAgilityPack fails to select notes with self closing tags

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to query all input nodes.  All of the nodes that are not self-closing are being returned fine, but the nodes that are self-closing are not.  Is there a way to address this that doesn't require me to changes the HTML?

Thanks!

Comment: You should show the expression you're currently using and some sample input on which it fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior. If you want to change it, you need to play with the `ElementFlags` collection, and for example, just remove INPUT from it, just like I explained for OPTION on a similar question here on SO: [XHTML Parsing with HTMLAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755486/xhtml-parsing-with-htmlagilitypack)